# CouchDB not running on Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to learn server-side swift and am having success deploying via Heroku as a Docker container but am struggling to get my database working when using couchdb with it. The database runs fine running locally but I can't seem to get it to run in the Docker container.

My current `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM ibmcom/swift-ubuntu:5.0.2

WORKDIR /ServerSideSwift
COPY . .

RUN swift build -c release
CMD .build/release/ServerSideSwift
```

So to add couchdb to this I tried to create a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: couchdb
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
```

Building the image works fine and running works well too but when it tried to create a new database(in swift) i get the errors i put in the swift code that show couchdb isnt running and therefore cant create any new databases.

Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Update 3: my current `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app-net

  db:
    image: couchdb
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    environment:
      COUCHDB_USER: Test
      COUCHDB_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
      - app-net
```

Comment: You should be able to do it all from a single docker-compose file. Is what you've provided your entire file?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. I've done some similar things hosting the LAMP stack with docker compose, although it has been a minute. The basic idea behind networking within containers should apply. I think maybe there is a syntax issue. I'm unable to recreate your environment right now so I won't provide an answer, but I think you could try `networks: - internal` instead of `net-web:`. Or, if you are using `net-web` at least set the `driver-opts` and `driver: bridge` in the networks section.

Comment: Thanks for replying @CaitLANJenner i have pushed my repo here, ignore the readme for now https://github.com/wrumble/ServerSideSwift trying to add `networks: - internal` gave me errors saying it didnt know what internal was adding `driver: bridge` didnt help either

Comment: @Wazza can you share the error log, what error it throws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change your connection string from "localhost" to "DB" to use Docker DNS. Then change the connection param to not use encryption.

Comment: Thanks for answering, whereabouts do i do this? where i initialize the couchdb `ConnectionProperties` or in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: The ConnectionProperties in App.swift. Your app resolves ''db" as the docker container running couchdb due to docker dns server feature. By the way, no need to use "link" and/or an extra network :)

Comment: So i update line 20 in `App.swift` to `let connectionProperties = ConnectionProperties(host: "db"` and my `docker-compose.yml` is the 3rd update in my question above but it still hits line 44 in`App.swift` when i run `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Should be fine now. So just a guess, maybe it is the secured parameter. Please try it with plain http -> secured: false

Comment: changing it to false got it working, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I will update my answer accordingly. Can you please accept it then?

Answer (score 2):

- CouchDB is accessible by default on localhost which will be localhost
  inside the container since you are using docker.
- you can try **exec** inside the CouchDB container and run **curl
  localhost:5984** and it should work.
- If you want to allow certain IPs to connect to your CouchDB server then you should use bind_address [config_docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/http.html).
- To allow all IPs use **bind_address = 0.0.0.0** in **local.ini**.

### bind_address

Defines the IP address by which CouchDB will be accessible.

```
[httpd]
bind_address = 127.0.0.1
```

To let CouchDB listen any available IP address, just setup 0.0.0.0 value:

```
[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

Add this config in your custom **local.ini** file and mount it inside the couchdb container in this path **/opt/couchdb/etc/**.

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app-net

  db:
    image: couchdb
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    environment:
      COUCHDB_USER: Test
      COUCHDB_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
     - path_to_local.ini:/opt/couchdb/etc/
    networks:
      - app-net
```

Comment: The Image documentation on Docker Hub states nothing about listening on localhost only. Most dockerized applications listen on 0.0.0.0 because they could not be used in a typical Microservice context otherwise